# Windows 10 stuck on boot mode on mac

Tags: macos, bootcamp, imac, windows, startup

I try to install Windows 10 on my Mac. After the installation I rebooted my Mac but it got stuck in Windows boot mode like in that picture.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: Additionally we are missing the mentioned picture!

Answer (score 1):

When it gives you the advanced settings option after 2 failed reboots, choose "Restart with Low-Res Video"